# JPA : reference to a generated JoinTable

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship

I have two entities : Product and Aisle.
A product can be in one or many aisles and an aisle can have one or more products.

```
@Entity 
public class Product{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "product_aisle",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "aisle_id") })
    private Set<Aisle> aisles = new HashSet<>();
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}


@Entity 
public class Aisle{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String row;
   private String shelf;
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="aisles")
   private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}
```

And I have a last entity : Salesman.
A salesman is responsible for a product in an aisle:

```
@Entity 
public class Salesman{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   /* ManyToOne to  ProductAisle ?*/

}
```

**Question** : How can I reference a Salesman to the auto-created join table (ProductAisle) with a "@ManyToOne" annotation ?

Regards

Comment: I think it's not possible, but you can create a new entity (ProductAisle) which represents the join table (i.e. it has a reference to a product and an aisle)

Comment: @SrThompson thank for your indication. Can you please elaborate your answer with a piece of code ? thanks

Comment: Could you please complete `Salesman` class, it is unclear what you want to achieve in terms of Java classes.

Comment: @MaxFarsikov this is the problem : I don't know how to write a `ManyToOne` annotation referencing to the `product_aisle` join table defined above.

Comment: Make ProductAisle an entity, and transform the ManyToMany into two OneToMany with ProductAisle.

Comment: @JBNizet could you please illustrate your idea with a piece of code ?

Comment: Your model knows nothing about any "join" table. An O-O model relates objects. So you have a relation to either a Product, or an Aisle. Your choice. There is no such class as a "Product-Aisle". Nothing JPA specific in that. It is O-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent a `Product` that is in a specific `Aisle` you need another entity. This is an example:

```
@Entity 
public class Product{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
   private Set<ProductAisle> productAisle = new HashSet<>;
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}


@Entity 
public class Aisle{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String row;
   private String shelf;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aisle")
   private Set<ProductAisle> productAisle = new HashSet<>();
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}

@Entity 
public class ProductAisle{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Product product;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Aisle aisle;
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}
```

And then your `Salesman` would point to a collection of `ProductAisle` instances, which maps a product with an aisle:

```
@Entity 
public class Salesman{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<ProductAisle> productAisle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both `Aisle` and `Product` have bi-directional mappings to each other, you can join any of them (or even both of them) to `Salesman` class, and you do not need to join service table at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with some code ?